# Undefined reference to '__divdi3'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker, linker-errors

Upon linking some code that performs division and modulo operations on an integer of type `long long` I receive the following two errors:

```
util.c:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference to '__divdi3'
util.c:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to '__moddi3'
```

I have also tried using `unsigned long long`, however that results in the following error:

```
util.c:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference to '__udivdi3'
util.c:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to '__umoddi3'
```

Replacing the `long long` with `int` or `long` fixes the problem, but I need to use `unsigned long long`.

I am using the following command line to compile and link the program:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel/util.c -o kernel/util.o
ld -o kernel32.bin -Ttext 0x500 kernel/util.o kernel/kernel.o --oformat binary
```

and this is the function:

```
char* itoa(unsigned long long i, char b[]){
    if (i == 0){
        b[0] = '0';
        b[1] = '\0';
        return b;
    }
    char const digit[] = "0123456789";
    char* p = b;
    if (i < 0){
        *p++ = '-';
        i *= -1;
    }
    unsigned long long shifter = i;
    while (shifter){
        ++p;
        shifter = shifter / 10;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    while (i){
        *--p = digit[i % 10];
        i = i / 10;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Clearly, the compiler is referencing `__udivdi3` to divide the integer but the linker can't find it..

By the way, the binary is to be used as a 32 bit operating system and therefore lacks many standard libraries

EDIT: I am using gcc 4.8.4 and ld 2.24

Comment: These are functions implemented in libgcc, which is a library providing implementations of basic operations not supported by the hardware you are targeting (64-bit division in this case).  You'll either need to provide your own implementations, or avoid those operations, or link with that library.

Comment: Wasn't it a border effect of freestanding compilation?

Comment: Just guessing, compiling with `-ffast-math` might make gcc use builtin functions for `long long` operations. Otherwise, you'd have to link with `divdi3.o`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Indirectly, but `-ffreestanding` is required since it's kernel stuff.

Comment: @YSC, I tried `-ffast-math` but sadly it didn't seem to affect the outcome.. Where could I find `divdi3.o`? I searched my whole system but couldn't find a file of that name.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [c++]; tag removed.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using?  Inasmuch as the answer may hinge on details of the available options and GCC's handling of them, the compiler version is important.

Comment: @JohnBollinger gcc 4.8.4 and ld 2.24

Comment: Did you tried __divti3 (or i was completely wrong)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When building code for an architecture that does not provide hardware support for the data type GCC uses as [`unsigned`] `long long`, GCC generates code for arithmetic operations on values of that type that involves calling functions provided by its own support library, `libgcc`.  The `__divdi3()` etc. are among those.  This is not the only way GCC could do it, but it is well suited to GCC's aim of supporting many architectures.

When instructed to act as a freestanding compiler, GCC does not automatically link libgcc, with the result that no implementation of these functions is automatically provided.  This has been the subject of previous complaints, such as [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16470) and [this later one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=32501).  The GCC maintainers take the position that this is not a GCC flaw, and that it does not render GCC non-conforming.  I find their reasoning questionable, but it's unlikely to change.  At minimum, this is a quality of implementation issue.

I do see where the GCC maintainers are coming from, however: a freestanding environment provides next to none of the standard library, and must not interpret most function calls except according to the code presented to it.  What, then, if that code contains explicit calls to functions with the same names as some of those in libgcc?  Unless the user explicitly says he wants libgcc, the compiler should not assume that it is those versions of the functions that are wanted.  The problem, though, is that if *the compiler* inserts such calls, then not only does it know which implementations are intended, but the result is wrong if an incompatible one is linked instead.  Thus, this is a problem of GCC's own making.

The bottom line is that you can explicitly request that libgcc be linked.  You will want to specify that it be linked statically, as you cannot rely on a dynamic linker in your context.  These additional link options should do it:

```
-static-libgcc -lgcc
```

Alternatively, you could write your own implementations of those functions, or crib the source from GCC, but I don't see why you would prefer either of those options.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! using the following command line still results in the same error though; `gcc static-libgcc -lgcc -ffreestanding -c kernel/util.c -o kernel/util.o `

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear: the options are for `gcc`, and it is desirable to use `gcc` as the linker driver.  To facilitate that, you can use gcc's `-Wl` option to pass options through to the linker.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to use ld separately.. Is there no other way

Comment: @RandomUser and why is that?  You can have a separate link step that runs the linker via `gcc`, and you can feed any options you like to it.  Why do you need to run it directly?

Comment: If function in question were `printf`, then this topic becomes much less controversial.

Answer (score 1):

Per this link: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gccint/Library-Calls.html

the functions of interest are defined in the `libgcc.a` library. (not in the `libgcc.so` library.)

I think your code will use the libgcc.a library if your link step contains the `-static` parameter

However, this link: https://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2006-04/msg00000.html

has the following to say:

Typically you link with gcc instead of ld to avoid just these types of problems.

I would either change it to link using gcc, or add the proper -L and -l options to get it to use the proper libgcc

Comment: The static and dynamic versions of libgcc provide the same functions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the wrong function:

— Runtime Function: long __divdi3 (long a, long b)

I guess that the correct function is:

— Runtime Function: long long __divti3 (long long a, long long b)

(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Integer-library-routines.html#Integer-library-routines)

Unfortunately I'm not sure if is implemented in your gcc version.