# implementation of __udivdi3 function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker, linker-errors, riscv

I have llvm compiler that supports Riscv vector intrinsic coding and a core on FPGA that is RV32IMV... I have written a C code for the core but when I compile it I get the following error:

```
error: undefined symbol: __udivdi3
```

I think it is because I don't have the necessary library added to my linker file for this purpose
but after I searched for the error I found this:
[Undefined reference to '__divdi3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532528/undefined-reference-to-divdi3)

At the end of this post, the author says:

> Alternatively, you could write your own implementations of those
> functions, or crib the source from GCC, but I don't see why you would
> prefer either of those options.

Can anyone suggest a piece of code that implements this function so that I can add it to my code?
I have already added this pices of code for memcpy and it works fine:

```
void* memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ((char*)dest)[i] = ((char*)src)[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question to copy-paste text *as text*.

Comment: Ok let me edit it

Comment: *`Can anyone suggest a piece of code that implements this function`* did google stop working? https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/wordsize-32/divdi3.c  Voting to close and DV

Comment: does the compiler complain when it compiles your `memcpy`? ?Always read the **WARNINGS**