# libgcc - Overview from the used functions by gcc depending on the architecture

Tags: c, gcc, bare-metal, libgcc

Is there somewhere an overview for functions in [libgcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html), which functions are used for a specific architecture (amd64, ARMv8, ...) ? Major projects like Linux or U-Boot uses their own implementation of these functions. Also a detailed overview on which `C` code snippet (as example) `gcc` uses them, would be nice. Currently it's for me an trial and error, when I don't link `libgcc`in my bare-metal projects.

Have searched a long time for such overview, but didn't find any. This question might not be ideal, but don't know where to ask.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you use some functions in your projects, then just implement these. Why do you need these from `libgcc` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh., I suspect the OP's problem is the one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34533569/2402272. Bottom line: at its own initiative, GCC sometimes introduces dependencies on libgcc functions that the user never explicitly requested.  If they are to provide implementations themselves then it helps to know what functions they need to provide.  But I would reiterate the alternative solution suggested in that answer: statically link libgcc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there somewhere an overview for functions in libgcc, which functions are used for a specific architecture (amd64, ARMv8, ...) ?

Not to my knowledge, no.  There is GCC documentation on [the contents of libgcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/index.html#toc-The-GCC-low-level-runtime-library), but I don't know any reference material summarizing which functions are used on which architectures.

> Major projects like Linux or U-Boot uses their own implementation of these functions.

I'm sure some do.  I'm not at all sure that *all* do.  If you don't have your own reasons for writing your own implementations, then you should strongly consider not doing so.

> Currently it's for me an trial and error, when I don't link `libgcc` in my bare-metal projects.

And that's indeed a viable way to figure it out, giving you exactly the information you need to successfully build those projects without relying on libgcc.  I understand wanting to know up front, but I don't think such advance knowledge actually helps you very much.  Whichever of those functions you need to provide yourself, you need to provide yourself either way.

But if you don't already, you should recognize that you always have the option of linking libgcc into your projects, including for freestanding implementations.  You may need to link it statically in some cases. Taking on responsibility for implementing GCC support functions yourself is your choice.

Comment: linking libgcc is the problem esp for arm, bad enough to make life easier to suck in functions you need from libgcc into your project, otherwise...just link in libgcc.

Comment: I don't have experience building for ARM, @old_timer, so I'm curious: does this mean that gcc has trouble with ARM in general?

Comment: the problem is you have two incompatible instruction sets that can exist in the same binary.  Yes, ideally the linker will put a trampoline in.  But when I first came across libgcc getting all this to work was a mess, and simply giving up and pulling source code from libgcc into your project saving pain.  The world may be different/better, could do some experiments.  But can easily see avoiding libgcc as a solution for a project

Comment: arm has several instruction sets actually, many thumb instruction sets ideally compatible back to the original (where support by gcc has been dropped BTW) so you would want to build a generic tool to the worst case.  other instruction sets have similar problems.  I guess I would say that use of ligbcc is trial and error in addition to if you need libgcc.  someone is welcome to prove me wrong with the current versions of gcc/libgcc...I remember the struggles with trying to get "multilib" etc libraries.

Comment: yes so building for cortex-m0 for example, simple division, aeabi_idiv,  using gcc since it knows where libgcc is -lgcc.  It grabs the arm based one which has arm instructions no warnings or errors that it is building a broken binary.

Comment: even when linking against the thumb directory version of libgcc you still get arm code in your thumb only binary.  it does appear to be written for armv4t though, all thumb variants, the few functions I looked at up front in the library.

Comment: instant fail and whatever pain that caused can lead folks to various solutions including lets just roll our own (vs maintaining a toolchain, the approach buildroot takes yes?)